# Windows Forms UserControls hosted in WPF spilling over side of window

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-controls, wpf-controls, winforms-interop

I'm converting an old WinForms app to WPF. To speed the migration, I'd like to host as many of the old app's `UserControls` as possible in `WindowsFormsHost` elements.

When I do, however, the controls seem to spill over the side of the window! It's as if the hosted control believes the window is about 20% wider than it actually is.

To illustrate what I mean, here's a shot of the WinForms control in the designer:

[image: AdvancedTabDesigner]

And here's a shot of the control once it's hosted in the app:

[image: AdvancedTabHosted]

Has anyone else seen this before? What is this caused by, and how do I fix it?

The `WindowsFormsHost` element is inside a `TabControl`'s `TabItem`, if that makes any difference.

**Edit:** Here is the relevant XML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:MyWinFormsApp;assembly=MyWinFormsApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Grid Row 1 -->
        <!-- Other controls here in row 1 -->

        <!-- Grid Row 2 -->
        <TabControl Grid.Row="2">
            <TabItem Header="Advanced">
                <WindowsFormsHost>
                    <forms:BinaryCommandControl/>
                </WindowsFormsHost>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Options">
                <WindowsFormsHost>
                    <forms:OptionsControl/>
                </WindowsFormsHost>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`BinaryCommandControl` and `OptionsControl` are both custom WinForms `UserControl` elements.

Comment: Can you post the XAML?

Comment: @Nzc Yes! I'll edit the question...

Comment: The window has a hard height/width set. Maybe remove that?